# How do I make apache run a cgi instead of showing the text?

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to install bugzilla 4 on ubuntu 11.04

I've added the following to my httpd.conf

```
<Directory “/var/www/dev.spincentre/bugzilla”>
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
   DirectoryIndex index.cgi
   AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

But when I go to the URL, apache shows the text of index.cgi instead of executing the script. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 19):

Did you load the mod_cgi module? You can see if the directory /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ has a symlink `cgi.load`. If there is no such symlink, you can create it by running

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

and then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can run `man a2enmod` to see what `a2enmod` does.

Comment: I had similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04 in a process of migration from old servers. I never thought cgi would have been disabled by default which is not with old server. This fixed it!. Plz recommend them the same at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199198/webserver-is-fetching-rather-than-executing-cgi-files-when-trying-to-run-bugzi. Thank you!

Comment: I have the symlink but cgi is still not running.

Answer (score 2):

When installing Apache 2.4 I had a number of issues to solve and also had the same issue with text showing instead of running the cgi. The solution is not the same as above, which is the solution for Apache 2.2

First, you need to download the 2.4 gz file and unpack. If you try to compile, it will complain the APR is not found, since it is no longer included. You need to download the apr and apr-util files from Apache and unpack them into the directory you are compiling Apache into the subdirectory called `srclib`, so your path would be `./httpd/srclib/apr` and `./httpd/srclib/apr-util`. You must also remove any version numbers from the directory name.

`cd` to your `/path/httpd` directory and the compile with

```
$ ./configure --with-included-apr
```

Your config will default to `PREFIX=/usr/local/apache2`

```
$ make

$ make install

$ vi PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
```

You will need to edit your `httpd.conf` file to get your cgi's to run

In my case I did the following:

change `Listen 80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

activate the line:

```
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
```

changed SeverName to:

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
```

changed the paths in `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` to suit my system

changed the path in `ScriptAlias`

enabled the line `Scriptsock cgisock`

changed the path in `<Directory>` after the `ScriptAlias` to suit my system

enabled the line `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`

saved the changes and started Apache with:

```
$ /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

Hope this helps anyone struggling with this ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm having trouble following, would you mind organising this a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

if your perl module is successfully running apache2, but when you open the page 
http://localhost/perl/mysite/ instead of displaying your file instead of executing the script, you only need to add a line of code to the **.htaccess** or **apache configuration file**,
That is :

```
DirectoryIndex: index.pl index.html index.php
```

Comment: The `DirectoryIndex` directive should not have a colon (`:`) after it. (However, I don't see how this addresses the problem as stated in the question?)