# What modules do I need to run perl CGI with apache?

Tags: apache2, configuration, perl, cgi

I have some CGI script using perl and I would like to make them work on Apache. I have the following installed  :

```
$ dpkg -l | grep perl | grep apach
ii  libapache-session-perl               1.90-1                                                all          modules for keeping persistent user data across HTTP requests
ii  libapache2-authcookie-perl           3.19-3                                                all          Perl Authentication and Authorization via cookies
ii  libapache2-mod-perl2                 2.0.8+httpd24-r1449661-6ubuntu1                       i386         Integration of perl with the Apache2 web server
ii  libapache2-mod-perl2-dev             2.0.8+httpd24-r1449661-6ubuntu1                       all          Integration of perl with the Apache2 web server - development files
ii  libapache2-mod-perl2-doc             2.0.8+httpd24-r1449661-6ubuntu1                       all          Integration of perl with the Apache2 web server - documentation
ii  libapache2-reload-perl               0.12-2                                                all          module for reloading Perl modules when changed on disk
ii  libapache2-request-perl              2.13-2.1                                              i386         generic Apache request library - Perl modules
ii  libapache2-sitecontrol-perl          1.05-1                                                all          perl web site authentication/authorization system
```

And in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I have added something like this :

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  Options +ExecCGI
  #AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
</Directory>
```

After that I get the script contents in the browser instead of getting it executed.

The mentioned script has the following permissions :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30146 mar  7 19:17 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/status.pl
```

If I put the following link

```
$ ll /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgi.load  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 mar  7 21:40 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgi.load -> ../mods-available/cgi.load
```

Then I get Error server 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve that with :

```
$ sudo a2enmod cgi
```

from that answer https://askubuntu.com/a/54259/23006